# Strictly diagonally dominant matrices are non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I try to find a good proof for invertibility of strictly diagonally dominant matrices (defined by $|m_{ii}|>\sum_{j\ne i}|m_{ij}|$). 
There is a proof of this in [this paper](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2007spring/projects/brakkenthal-paper.pdf) but I'm wondering whether there are are better proof such as using determinant, etc to show that the matrix is non singular.

Comment: Use [Gershgorin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). Wiki has the proof.

Comment: The above can be generalized to the larger class of *weakly chained diagonally dominant matrices*. For an elementary proof of the nonsingularity, also using Gershgorin's theorem, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03928v2.pdf Definition 3.1 and Lemma 3.2 on page 5. Note that nonsingularity is not necessarily true for weakly diagonally dominant matrices (a simple counterexample is $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
+1 & -1\\
-1 & +1
\end{array}\right)$)

Answer (score 27):

The proof in the PDF (Theorem 1.1) is very elementary. The crux of the argument is that if $M$ is strictly diagonally dominant and singular, then there exists a vector $u \neq 0$ with
$$Mu = 0.$$

$u$ has some entry $u_i > 0$ of largest magnitude. Then

\begin{align*}
\sum_j m_{ij} u_j &= 0\\
m_{ii} u_i &= -\sum_{j\neq i} m_{ij}u_j\\
m_{ii} &= -\sum_{j\neq i} \frac{u_j}{u_i}m_{ij}\\
|m_{ii}| &\leq \sum_{j\neq i} \left|\frac{u_j}{u_i}m_{ij}\right|\\
|m_{ii}| &\leq \sum_{j\neq i} |m_{ij}|,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

I'm skeptical you will find a significantly more elementary proof. Incidentally, though, the Gershgorin circle theorem (also described in your PDF) is very beautiful and gives geometric intuition for why no eigenvalue can be zero.

Comment: How do you go from the prior to last inequality to the last? $u_j/u_i$ could be a very large number thus taking it out of the absolute value can make it smaller, how do you know the inequality is preserved?

Comment: @Makogan This is because $u_i>0$ was chosen to be the largest entry in the vector $u$ (this is mentioned in the answer just before the string of displayed equations). So, $|u_j/u_i|\leq 1$ for each $j\neq i$.

Answer (score 2):

I would probe it a bit tangentially. And not because it will be simpler, but because it gives an excuse to show an application. I would take an iterative method, like [Jacobi's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method), and show that it converges in this case; and that it converges to a unique solution. This, incidentally implies the matrix is non-singular.

How does it work exactly?

For the system $Ax=b$, Jacobi's method consists in writing $A=D+R$, where $D$ is diagonal and $R$ has zeros in the diagonal. Then you define the recurrence

$$x_{n+1}=D^{-1}(b-Rx_{n}).$$

Now we can show that it converges.

We have

\begin{align}||x_m-x_n||&=||\sum_{k=n}^{m}(D^{-1}R)^kb-((D^{-1}R)^{m}-(D^{-1}R)^{n})x_0||\\
&\leq\sum_{k=n}^{m}||D^{-1}R||^k||b||+\left(||D^{-1}R||^m+||D^{-1}R||^n\right)||x_0|| \end{align}

For the norm $||\cdot||:=||\cdot||_{\infty}$, the matrix norm is bounded by the maximum of the sums of the absolute values of its entries in each row. Therefore $$||D^{-1}R||$$ is less than some number less than $1$. For this reason the sum above can be as small as you want for $n,m$ large. This shows the convergence of the sequence.

If it clear too that it has to converge to any solution of the system $Ax=b$. To see this we use the same argument above but placing a solution $x$ in place of $x_m$. We use that $Ax=b$, i.e. $x=D^{-1}(b-Rx)$ and we get it. So $x_n$ converges to any solution. Since it is a convergent sequence it converges to only one thing so there is only one solution to the system.

Comment: Nice reversion of the usual teaching order :-) However, $\|D^{-1}\|$ seems not necessarily $<1$ to me (should not be required anyway), and I do not see the uniqueness from the mere convergence yet.

Comment: Oh, true. Let me correct it.

Comment: For uniqueness I was getting lazy while writing. It doesn't follow from convergence but from the same proof of convergence but putting $x$ instead of $x_m$ to show that the sequence converges to any solution. Then, since it converges, it is to only one thing.

Comment: The fact that every such sequence converges does not imply that all the sequences have the same limit. However, it would be sufficient to show that given any particular solution $x^*$, starting with any distance from that $x^*$ decreases that distance by a factor strictly less than $1$.

Comment: Yes, I am, if not saying, trying to say what you just said. When you put that $x^{*}$ instead of $x_m$ in the inequalities above, that is what you prove: That $x_n\rightarrow x^{*}$. Therefore it happens for any solution $x^{*}$ the system may have. Since the sequence converges and the limit is unique then there is a unique $x^{*}$.

Comment: So it could be cleaned up to: $x_{n+1}-x^* = -D^{-1}R(x_n-x^*)$. No $\sum$ required. Then the norm estimate, and you are done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9905/discussion-between-ccorn-and-rgb)

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't think of focusing on the component of largest magnitude, below was my approach, as a variation of user7530's proof.

Assume that $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}} = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{0}}.$

For each $i = \overline{1, n},$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j = 1}^nx_jm_{ij} &= 0\Rightarrow -x_im_{ii} = \sum_{j = 1,j \neq i}^nx_jm_{ij}\\
\sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^n|x_i||m_{ij}| \le |x_i||m_{ij}| = |x_im_{ii}| &= \left|\sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^nx_jm_{ij}\right|\le\sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^n|x_jm_{ij}| = \sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^n|x_j||m_{ij}|\\
Q_i &:= \sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^n(|x_i| - |x_j|)|m_{ij}| \le 0
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that if $x_i\neq 0,$ the left most inequality is strictly smaller, then $Q_i < 0.$ Also, if $Q_i = 0\Rightarrow x_i = 0.$

---

- If there exists $x_i \neq 0,$ as $Q_i < 0,$ it must be that $|x_i| < |x_k|,$ for some $k\neq i.$
- Then comes $x_k \neq 0,$ it similarly must be that $|x_k| < |x_l|,$ for some $l\notin \{ k, i\} := D_l,$ so $x_l \neq 0.$
- By continuing this way, as any subsequent index differs from those coming before it, $D_l$ will reach a state in which it consists of all indices running from $1$ to $n$ but one, say $m.$

  As $x_l\neq 0,$ to have $Q_l < 0$ valid, it must be that $|x_l| < |x_m|.$

  So, $x_m\neq 0.$ But, as $|x_m| > |x_k|,\,\forall k\in D_m,$ which contains at least one index, it must be that $Q_m > 0.$ A contradiction because $Q_m < 0.$

---

Alternatively, if taking the idea of focusing on the component that has the largest magnitude, say $x_m.$

Therefore, as $|x_m|\ge |x_i|,\,\forall i = \overline{1, n},$ then $Q_m\ge 0.$ Nevertheless, $Q_m\le 0,$ then $Q_m = 0.$ This equality holds when all the components of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}}$ have the same magnitude, and also $x_m = 0.$

---

So, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}} = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{0}}\Rightarrow\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}} = \boldsymbol{\mathrm{0}}.$ This means that the columns of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}$ are linearly independent.

Thus, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{M}}$ is non-singular.

Comment: How do you have the left-most inequality?

Comment: Basically, how do you get the inequality and then the equality $\sum_{j = 1, j\neq i}^n|x_i||m_{ij}| \le |x_i||m_{ij}| = |x_im_{ii}|$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ and $F$ be the diagonal and the off-diagonal parts of $M$  respectively. Let $\mathbf1$ be the vector of ones. Since $M$ is strictly diagonally dominant, $(|D|-|F|)\mathbf1$ is a positive vector, where the notation $|\cdot|$ means the entrywise absolute value of a matrix or a vector. Hence $v^T(|D|-|F|)\mathbf1>0$ for every nonnegative but nonzero vector $v$.

Now, if $x^TM=0$, then $x^TD=-x^TF$. Hence $|x|^T|D|=|x^TD|=|x^TF|\le |x|^T|F|$. In turn, $|x|^T(|D|-|F|)\mathbf1\le0$. Therefore $|x|$ must be zero, i.e., $x$ must be zero. Thus $M$ is nonsingular.