# Show that B is a nonsingular matrix (not that obvious).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

How would you proceed if you were asked in an interview to show that B is a nonsingular matrix (in an elegant way)?

$$B= \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1.25& −0.50& 0.15\\ 0.15& 2& 1.25& −1.50\\ −0.45& 0.25& 3& 1.25\\ 0.25& −0.15& 0.25& 4\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

In my opinion, taking the time to compute the determinant of this $4\times4$ matrix during the interview would not be appreciated by the interviewer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

$B^T$ is non-singular because it is a strict [diagonally dominant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix). So $B$ is non-singular as well.

Comment: [+1} Having a look at the coefficients shows that your answer is in the spirit of this "test". A reference for the invertibility proof :(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456722/strictly-diagonally-dominant-matrices-are-non-singular)

Comment: @Nebr Note the transpose. Look at the columns of $B$.

Comment: $|1| \overset{?}{>} |1.25| + |-0.5| + |0.15| = 1.90$?

Comment: @dantopa You need to look at the columns not at the rows here. Then you know that the transpose of a nonsingular matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: The transpose notation is unnecessarily confusing and nonstandard. That's why people are ignoring it and getting confused about the rows. Just use $B^\top$ or something.

Comment: @Mehrdad In France it is a very common notation. But I will edit since this one tends to be a problem for a lot of people here.

Answer (score 40):

Another approach:

Multiply by a constant to make it an integer matrix: in this case, consider the matrix $20B$, which is an integer matrix. Show that its determinant is non-zero modulo some small prime, eg: 2 or 3.

Comment: Mod 2 works, and row reducing the mod 2 version is also easy.

Comment: +1 While the other example is ingenious it seems like a fairly obscure (never heard of it and I have a masters in abstract algebra) theorem. This seems like the more usual approach.

Comment: @DRF It is often mentionned in numerical linear algebra courses. If you are more into abstract algebra, as you said, that may explain why you have never heard of it.

Comment: Also, those of us who hadn't heard before of the "diagonally dominant" theorem, now know something new and interesting.

Comment: How to "Show that its determinant is non-zero modulo some small prime, eg: 2 or 3"?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic, reduce each integer entry modulo 2, then compute the determinant modulo 2.

Comment: @Aravind Oh I see. So I still have to compute a 4 x 4 determinant, but it will have much, much simpler calculations involved (i.e. multiplying and adding/subtracting zeros and ones).

Comment: @Hamsteriffic: Yes, especially mod 2 because minus and plus are the same thing, so you don't even have to be careful with sign.  Everything reduces to a sum of $1$s and you hope for an odd number of them.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @Hamsteriffic: Your goal is to show the determinant is nonzero mod $2$, but that doesn't have to be by *computing* the determinant. Any method of proving the determinant nonzero will suffice, such as row reducing it to the identity. (although, since it's mod $2$, doing so would prove the determinant is $1$)

Comment: @Hurkyl And `*20 mod 2` just means "does it end in 0.05?".  And ... 6? row operations gives you an upper triangular matrix with 1s on the diagonal.  Not quite as slick as the diagonally dominant matrix, but pretty slick.

Comment: I upvoted this answer yesterday, but I must say this approach is risky: the chance that the determinant is zero in mod 2 arithmetic is 71%, which is very high. Even in mod 3 arithmetic, the chance is 44%, just barely below one half. Of course, it should be much less likely that the determinant is divisible by 6, but you won't look good in an interview if your trick fails twice in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Something that will always work with low complexity and not dependent on which matrix:

1. Take a random vector
2. Loop over columns / rows:

   - Remove projection with current row/col

If after three (or $n-1$) removed projections is not parallel to last vector ( up to precision ) then there is a non-zero sized null-space.

I'm very sure that the chance of accidentally hitting a subspace in the value space is abysmally small.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

Use Gaussian elimination on $B$ to yield an upper-triangular matrix. Nonzeros on the diagonal of the resulting upper-triangular matrix means that $B$ is nonsingular.

(OP asked for an elegant way to do this; however, "elegant" was not defined. IMHO, Gaussian elimination is *way* more elegant than computing the determinant.)