# How to show that this matrix is symmetric definite positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I need help.
We want to show that the matrix $A$ is symmetric definite positive for all $n$ where $n$ is the size of the matrix $A$.

Here is $A$ :
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1&  -1&  0& ...& 0\\ 
 -1&  2&  -1& \ddots & \vdots\\ 
 0&  -1&  2& \ddots &0\\ 
 \vdots &  \ddots &  \ddots&  \ddots &-1 \\
0 & ...  &0 & -1& 2
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

I tried brute forcing by calculating for $x$ a vector of size $n$, $x^TAx$, but it seems tricky.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

The matrix is symmetric and [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), so positive semidefinite. To show that it is actually positive definite, you need to check that the kernel is null. Take a vector in the kernel. You notice that the first two components are equal, and then, the components are in arithmetic progression, but then notice the relation between the last two components. Thus the vector is $0$.

$\bf{Added:}$. Place $-\epsilon < 0$ instead of $-1$, and call the matrix $M_{\epsilon}$.  For every $\epsilon \in [0,1)$ the matrix is strictly diagonally dominant, so the eigenvalues are not $0$. The eigenvalues of $M_{\epsilon}$ vary continuously with $\epsilon$. Now the eigenvalues of $M_{0}$ are $>0$, so no eigenvalue of $M= M_1$ can be negative.

Comment: I understant how to show that the kernel is {0} (there are plenty of method). What i do not understant is the link between diagonally dominant and positive definite ... is there a proof to make it clearer ? thank you

Comment: @Wil123: added some details.

Comment: That is brilliant !! I would never have thought of that. I just have one question. Why does the eigenvalues varie continuously with epsilon ? is it because we have a kind of a polyome with epsilon and the determinant ... ?? Can you plz give a quick justification ? Thank you again

Comment: @Wil123: The eigenvalues depende continously on the entries. I have an answer somewhere on the site. Btw, I found another answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2805429/diagonal-elements-of-a-symmetric-matrix-and-positive-definiteness/2805510#2805510 where I show directly that diagonally dominant implies positive (semi)definite.

Comment: @Wil123: your idea with the determinants is clearer. We just check that every leading minor of $M_{\epsilon}$ is never $0$, so it cannot be negative for any $\epsilon$, since all are positive for $M_0$. We bypass the continuity of eigenvalues. Now it is clearer for me too. Great!!

Comment: Perfect !!! Thanks for the elegant solution

Comment: @Wil123: You are very welcome! That helped me too...

Answer (score 3):

This follows directly from the Cholesky decomposition $A=(I-J)^T(I-J)$, where $J$ is the $n\times n$ upper triangular nilpotent Jordan block.

Comment: This works and it is elegant. However my question is from a math problem where Question 1 is prove that A is symetric positive and Question 2 is give the cholesky factorisation. Lol

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n$ be the determinant of the $n$th leading principal minor.

We can quickly check that $f_1=1, f_2= 1$ and
$f_n = 2f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}$. It is not hard to check that the solution is $f_n =1$.

Hence $A$ is positive definite by Sylvester's criterion.

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric matrix  is positive definite iff its leading principal minors are positive. It should be easy to show it by induction (maybe you can expand the determinants by Laplace on the last column).