# Prove A is nonsingular given $|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j=1,j\neq{i}}^n|a_{ij}|$ $, i=1,2,...n$

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is taken from Linear Algebra by Zhang, Fuzhen.

> Show that $A$ is nonsingular if  $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(C)$ satisfies
>
> $|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j=1,j\neq{i}}^n|a_{ij}|$ $, i=1,2,...n$

Here is the proof given:

> It suffices to show that $Ax = 0$ has only the trivial solution $0$. Suppose that $Ax = 0$ has a nonzero solution
>
> $x = (k_1, k_2,..., k_n).$
>
> Let $|k_s|= \max_{1<i<n} {|k_i|}$
> Then $|k_s|$ ≠ 0.
>
> However, the s-th equation of $Ax = 0$ is
>
> $a_{s1}k_1 + a_{s2}k_2 + ... + a_{ss}k_s + ... + a_{sn}k_n = 0$
>
> Thus
>
> $a_{ss}k_s=-\sum_{j=1,j\neq{s}}^n{a_{sj}k_j}$
> and
>
> $a_{ss}\le\sum_{j=1,j\neq{s}}^n{|a_{sj}\frac{k_j}{k_s}|}<\sum_{j=1,j\neq{i}}^n|a_{ij}|$ which is a contradiction.

I understand the proof except $|k_s|=\max_{1<i<n} {|k_i|}$. Why does $k_s$ (which is the coefficient of $a_{ss}$) have to be the maximum? If it is not the maximum how do you generalize?

Comment: you don't "understand the proof except $|k_s| = \max |k_i|$" if you don't understand why $k_s$ has to be the maximum

Comment: The last line is  where you'll get a problem if you do not make that assumption

Comment: The set $\{|k_1|,...,|k_n|\}$ is a finite set of real numbers, so you can find $1\le s\le n$ such that $|k_s|=\max_{1\le i\le n}k_i$

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 sure, but $k_s$ is also the coefficient of $a_{ss}$

Comment: Look at it like this, you are choosing an $s$ such that $|k_s|$ is maximum among all the $k_i$. This exists as there are only finitely many $k's$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456722/strictly-diagonally-dominant-matrices-are-non-singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k_s$ being the maximum means $\left|\frac{k_j}{k_s}\right|\leq1$, which is necessary for the last line of your proof. Specifically, for
$$
\sum_{j=1,j\neq{s}}^n\left|a_{sj}\frac{k_j}{k_s}\right|\leq\sum_{j=1,j\neq{s}}^n\left|a_{sj}\right|
$$
(Note that the proof wrongfully inserts a $<$ here, rather than $\leq$; a priori nothing stops all the $k_j$ from being equal. Also, the indices should still be $s$ rather than $i$ on the right-hand side.)

You pick $s$ so that $k_s$ is the largest coefficient in $x$. Then you use the $s$th row of $A$, so that the largest entry in $x$ lines up with diagonal entry in $A$.

Comment: @EminOzkan You pick $s$ so that $k_s$ is the largest coefficient in $x$. Then you use the $s$th row of $A$, so that the largest entry in $x$ lines up with  diagonal entry in $A$.

Comment: Thank you. That was the answer I was looking for. Can a comment be the answer a question?

Comment: @EminOzkan Not really. But I can add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $|k_s|$ is not the maximum value of $|k_1|,\dots, |k_n|$, then we do cannot say that $\frac{k_j}{k_s}a_{sj} < |a_{sj}|$, and therefore, the last line of the proof is not correct.